# Not in clause on a column with Null values

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with 10 odd columns, one of them being 'Status'.

I wanted to fetch all rows where Status is not Rejected, so I wrote the following query on Hive:

```
select * from table1 where status <> 'Rejected'
```

However Hive is not returning me rows where the Status was Null. I changed the query to

```
select * from table1 where status <> 'Rejected' or status is Null
```

But I can't find any documentation to understand why this is happening.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: That is how `NULL` works.  It should be in documentation that describes `NULL` values for all databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive implements the `NULL`-safe comparison operator.  So you can do:

```
select *
from table1
where not status <=> 'Rejected' ;
```

As for your question, it is a pretty basic question on what `NULL` means in databases.  It doesn't mean "missing", it means "unknown".  Almost all comparison operations return `NULL` when either operand is `NULL` -- the exceptions are operands (such as `<=>`, `is not null` and `is null`) that are specific designed to handle `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

`null` isn't a value, it's the lack thereof. Whenever you try to use it in a context of the value, the result would be "unkonwn". You can think about it like this - "is an unknown (=null) value different from 'Rejected'? We don't know."

Thus, you need to specifically handle it with the `is [not]` operator. You can think of the second `where` clause you shared as "all the statuses that are not known to have the value 'Rejected'".